App react native crash on click on ios module
I have a problem in my react native app, I have a sub module in it, which [is invoked from another project, it always worked and now when I click on the link that calls the sub module the app is crashing, I'm going to send it the error report so someone can help me
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 4605731B-4725-4D6D-A483-320E9688BB91
CrashReporter Key:   9AB37C36-78A4-2BDA-E832-E338129DED5A
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,3
Process:             Natura [79300]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E46CC5DE-062F-47B6-8F5E-6C7E15C9BEC0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BDF4FC3A-5703-4D00-9AC5-A43EC1712DC5/Natura.app/Natura
Identifier:          net.natura.fv
Version:             4.5.0 (261)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [69103]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E46CC5DE-062F-47B6-8F5E-6C7E15C9BEC0 [65176]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1414]

Date/Time:           2024-08-26 12:40:13.3542 -0300
Launch Time:         2024-08-26 12:39:33.9155 -0300
OS Version:          macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Natura [79300]

Triggered by Thread:  10

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x111415521 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x10d7567e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Natura                                 0x10236b111 RCTFormatError + 0 (RCTAssert.m:166)
3   Natura                                 0x1023ef166 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 511 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:78)
4   Natura                                 0x1023efb66 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1735 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:152)
5   CoreFoundation                         0x11141c15c __invoking___ + 140
6   CoreFoundation                         0x111419483 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 302
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1114196f3 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 70
8   Natura                                 0x1023a08b7 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 583 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:587)
9   Natura                                 0x1023a2f86 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 574 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 folly::Optional<folly::dynamic>::StorageNonTriviallyDestructible::clear() + 0 (Optional.h:419) [inlined]
11  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 folly::Optional<folly::dynamic>::StorageNonTriviallyDestructible::~StorageNonTriviallyDestructible() + 0 (Optional.h:416) [inlined]
12  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 folly::Optional<folly::dynamic>::StorageNonTriviallyDestructible::~StorageNonTriviallyDestructible() + 0 (Optional.h:416) [inlined]
13  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 folly::Optional<folly::dynamic>::~Optional() + 0 (Optional.h:102) [inlined]
14  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 folly::Optional<folly::dynamic>::~Optional() + 0 (Optional.h:102) [inlined]
15  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 74 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104) [inlined]
16  Natura                                 0x1023a2b83 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 110 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122ac3ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122ad6d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122b527d _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1228
20  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122b5e17 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 406
21  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122c19a8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 276
22  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1122c0f72 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 552
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11388ab84 _pthread_wqthread + 327
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x113889acf start_wqthread + 15 ```

